# How to do form validation using java?

Tags: java, validation

How to do form validation using java by interacting with the oracle database (I mean user and password validation)?

Comment: ya gotta give us more than that, dude.

Comment: You want client side validation or server side validation

Comment: You always want server side validation

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Hibernate Validator](https://www.hibernate.org/412.html) or [Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/)